# mssql and dynamic column from another table

Tags: sql-server

i have this select statement:

```
select * from folder
inner join subprops on folder.id = subprop.id
inner join props on props.id = subprops.id
inner join products on product.feature = subprop.val
```

`product.feature` has values for example 300,301
and `subprop.val` has these values as well

i have column `props.colname`
and i want to make the third inner join dynamicly by the `props.colname` value
with some kind of eval() or anything else

```
inner join products on product.eval(props.colname) = subprop.val
```

can you think about anything? i can't find solution for that without dynamic statement or loop - that i don't want to do

Comment: A single value `300,301` sounds as if you should refactor your database schema instead. Create another table where one record has 300 and another has 301 and both link to the main table via foreign key. That process is called database normalization and very important. Then the query is simple and efficient.

Comment: this is the case... i have diff products with diff value at feature. either 300 or 301 (it is just an example)